# Automator to find specific file in folder and then delete the folder

Tags: macos, automator, workflow

I have created an Automator workflow which asks the user for a folder and then it looks for files that meet x requirements. It then copies those files to another location.

How can I then make it delete that specified folder after it has been copied? (including any other files in that folder)

Here is a picture of my current flow, for debugging purposes I have not copied the matched files to another location but had them output into a textfile.
[image]

Comment: Please show your current workflow

Comment: @slhck I have now updated the post